# use html5 video player only if browser is Safari

Tags: html, video, html5-video, browser-detection

I would like to use the html5 video tag only if the users browser is Safari, and if it is not, use a flash video player.

The code below does not work (`<!--[if Safari]>` conditional is not valid), but it may give you an idea of what i am looking for

```
<!--[if Safari]>
<video id="player" width="480" controls>
  <source src="path/to/movie.mov" />
</video>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !Safari]>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var flashvars = {};
  var params = {
      allowscriptaccess: "true",
      file:"path/to/movie.mov"
  };
  var attributes = {};

  swfobject.embedSWF("swf/player.swf", "player", "640", "480", "9.0.0", flashvars, params, attributes);

</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Never** use browser detection. Use feature detection instead. You can use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) for that, but in this case, you don't need any JavaScript at all to fallback to Flash if the browser doesn't support HTML5's `<video>` element.

[See this article at Nettuts+.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-html-5-video-with-a-fallback-to-flash/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I would like people to view the movies on their i%Apple% products (iPhone, iPod, iPad).  The reason I would only like to use the video tag in safari is because I have many movies encoded as .mov files, and do not want to re-encode them a .ogv files.

Comment: You can just skip that part, but remember to include a Flash fallback.

Comment: [Jeremy Keith's HTML5 book](http://books.alistapart.com/products/html5-for-web-designers) has an excellent chapter about doing this right.